# Как вывести сообщение только один раз при нескольких совпадениях?

Tags: java

ребята подскажите , плиз, как вывести сообщение только один раз при нескольких совпадениях?

Условие: Сравнить элементы массива с заранее заданными константами x, y, z и если массив содержит хотя бы одну из констант, вывести текст "Данное значение имеется в константах".

```
Код:

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 10;
    int y = 12;
    int z = 2;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter array length: ");
    int size = input.nextInt();
    int array[] = new int[size];
    System.out.println("Insert array elements: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = input.nextInt();
        if (array[i] == x | array[i] == y | array[i] == z )
                System.out.println("Данное значение имеется в константах");

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: остановите цикл. после вывода сообщения используйте break

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. вы нашли одно совпадение, то дальше искать не имеет смысла и цикл можно завершать

```java
if (array[i] == x | array[i] == y | array[i] == z )
  System.out.println("Данное значение имеется в константах");
  break;
}
```

Comment: break остановит инициализацию элементов массива

Comment: @стасевич Читаем ТЗ `Сравнить элементы массива с заранее заданными константами`. То что автор решил совместить инициализацию и поиск - это его ошибка. При такой реализации как у автора, массив вообще не нужен

Comment: ну да.... согласен

Answer (score 1):

создай булеву переменную `boolean flag = false;`

и в цикле при совпадении меняй её

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

            if (array[i] == x | array[i] == y | array[i] == z)
                flag = true;
        }
        if (flag) System.out.println("Данное значение имеется в константах");
```

и лучше используй `Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());`
т.к. nextInt() считывает число и после ввода числа и нажатия enter перевод строки `"\n"` остаётся в буфере

Answer (score 0):

Вот мое решение:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int x = 10;
            int y = 12;
            int z = 2;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter array length: ");
            int size = input.nextInt();
            int [] array = new int[size];
            System.out.println("Insert array elements: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                array[i] = input.nextInt();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                if (array[i] == x | array[i] == y | array[i] == z ){
                    System.out.println("Данное значение имеется в константах");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

У вас вывод находится в for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = input.nextInt();
        if (array[i] == x | array[i] == y | array[i] == z )
                System.out.println("Данное значение имеется в константах");
```

При переборе значений если указать существующую константу будет выводиться сообщение "Данное значение имеется в константах", каждый раз когда будет угадана константа.

В примере выше, добавлен дополнительный (отдельный) блок for в котором уже сравниваем каждое значение с константой. Вывод после данного кода будет один.